# SQL Server 2008 query to get mixed data from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Someone please tell me the SQL query to get the result....

Thanks!

[image]

From the above two tables, I want to get the `Photo`, `Name`, `Id of max(id)` from `Table-A` for each `category_id` for which the `parent_id` in `Table-B` is `1` i.e.

```
1005 E Byte Apple 3
1002 B Byte Banana 5
1007 G Byte Orange 6
1011 K Byte Mango 7
```

Comment: Seriously?, no explaining what are your tables, what are the results you want, nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below;

```
Select TBLA.ID, TBLA.Name, TBLA.Photo, TBLB.Category_Name, TBLB.Category_ID
From [table-B] TBLB
Inner Join [table-a] TBLA On TBLA.Category_ID = TBLB.Category_ID
Where TBLB.Parent_ID = 1 
And TBLA.ID = (Select Max(ID) 
      From [table-a]
      Where Category_ID = TBLB.Category_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.id,a.name,a.photo,b.category_name,b.category_id
from table-A a join table-B s ON a.category_id = b.category_id
where parent_id = 1
```